# How can I get my JavaScript popup to show only once per session?

Tags: javascript, popup

I've created a JavaScript code for a website popup. I need the popup to only appear when the user scrolls back to the top of the page and only appear once per session.

I used the function below to tell the popup to appear when the user scrolls back to the top:

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
      if (window.pageYOffset === 0) {
```

It works, however the popup now appears every time the user scrolls to the top and not only once per session like I had coded it to.

I want to achieve this using only JavaScript

Here is a link where you can see it in action >> https://digitalcloud.co.za/kiron/

This is the full script

```
<script>
    // Check if the popup has already been shown during the current session
    if (!sessionStorage.getItem('popupShown')) {
        window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
      if (window.pageYOffset === 0) {
            var popup = document.createElement("div");
            popup.style.position = "fixed";
            popup.style.top = "0";
            popup.style.left = "0";
            popup.style.zIndex = "999";
            popup.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)";
            popup.style.width = "100vw";
            popup.style.height = "100vh";
            popup.style.display = "flex";
            popup.style.alignItems = "center";
            popup.style.justifyContent = "center";
            var innerPopup = document.createElement("div");
            innerPopup.style.backgroundColor = "black";
            innerPopup.style.display = "flex";
            innerPopup.style.flexDirection = "column";
            innerPopup.style.alignItems = "center";
            innerPopup.style.justifyContent = "center";
            innerPopup.style.padding = "40px";
            innerPopup.style.margin = "35px";
            innerPopup.style.borderRadius = "25px";

            var img = document.createElement("img");
img.src = "https://digitalcloud.co.za/wp-content/uploads/2023/01/kerridge_pop_up_illustration.png ";
img.alt = "Find out about Kerridge’s core solution ";
img.style.width = "25%";
img.style.cursor = "pointer";
innerPopup.appendChild(img);

            var text = document.createElement("p");
            text.innerHTML = "Interested to find out more about our core solution?";
            text.style.color = "white";
            text.style.marginTop = "50px";
            text.style.textAlign = "center";
            text.style.fontSize = "20px";
            innerPopup.appendChild(text);

            var button = document.createElement("button");
            button.innerHTML = "Book a free demo today";
            button.style.backgroundColor = "#E8017B";
            button.style.color = "white";
            button.style.fontSize = "20px";
            button.style.padding = "15px";
            button.style.borderRadius = "50px"
            button.style.border = "none"
            button.onclick = function() {
                location.href = "https://digitalcloud.co.za/ ";
            }
            innerPopup.appendChild(button);
            
            var secondText = document.createElement("p");
            secondText.innerHTML = "Stay up to date with the latest Kerridge product updates and existing announcements";
            secondText.style.color = "white";
            secondText.style.marginTop = "50px";
            secondText.style.textAlign = "center";
            secondText.style.fontSize = "20px";
            innerPopup.appendChild(secondText);
            
            var secondButton = document.createElement("button");
                secondButton.innerHTML = "Sign up to our Newsletter";
                secondButton.style.color = "#E8017B";
                secondButton.style.background = "transparent";
                secondButton.style.border = "none";
                secondButton.style.fontSize = "20px";
                secondButton.onclick = function() {
                 location.href = "https://digitalcloud.co.za/ ";
                }
                
                innerPopup.appendChild(secondButton);

            var closeBtn = document.createElement("div");
            closeBtn.style.position = "absolute";
            closeBtn.style.top = "50px";
            closeBtn.style.right = "50px";
            closeBtn.style.cursor = "pointer";
            closeBtn.style.width = "60px";
            closeBtn.style.height = "60px";
            closeBtn.style.borderRadius = "50%";
            closeBtn.style.backgroundColor = "#E8017B";
            closeBtn.style.display = "flex";
            closeBtn.style.alignItems = "center";
            closeBtn.style.justifyContent = "center";

closeBtn.setAttribute("tabindex", "0");
closeBtn.setAttribute("role", "button");
closeBtn.setAttribute("aria-label", "Close");

closeBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  // Add logic to close something here
  popup.remove();
});

closeBtn.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
  if (event.key === "Enter" || event.key === " ") {
    // Add logic to close something here
    popup.remove();
  }
});

            var closeX = document.createElement("div");
            closeX.innerHTML = "X";
            closeX.style.color = "white";
            closeX.style.fontWeight = "bold";

            closeBtn.appendChild(closeX);
            closeBtn.onclick = function() {
                popup.remove();
            }
            innerPopup.appendChild(closeBtn);

            popup.appendChild(innerPopup);
            document.body.appendChild(popup);
            // Set a value in sessionStorage indicating that the popup has been shown
            sessionStorage.setItem('popupShown', 'true');
        };
    }
</script>
```

I used a function to ensure the popup only appears when the user scrolls to the top but I need it to only appear once per session.

Answer (score 0):

Create a variable somewhere before your function, for example `index = 0`, then, within your scroll function, add `1` to the `index` > `index += 1`, and then, within your function, add `if` statement, that will check whether the `index` is `0`, which will mean that it has not yet been scrolled, and if it is, then it has been scrolled and will not proceed to the rest of the function.

```
let index = 0;
window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
   if (window.pageYOffset === 0) {
      index += 1;
      if (index <= 0) {
          *your code*
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: I think you mean `index <= 0` or `index == 0`

Comment: You are right, sorry for my mistake, answer edited.

Answer (score 0):

Unbind the event after it is shown to the user so it is not called again

```
const scrollCode = () {
  if (window.pageYOffset === 0) {
    sessionStorage.setItem('popupShown', '1');
    window.removeEventListener('scroll', scrollCode);
    /* your pop up code */
  }
};

if (!sessionStorage.getItem('popupShown') {
  window.addEventListener('scroll', scrollCode)
}
```